# Root Samsung Galaxy Core i8262 manually

Tags: rooting, samsung

I tried almost every readymade app like Framaroot, Root Genius, etc. to root my Samsung Galaxy Core i8262 , but I didn't succeed.

I want to root it manually but did not have Linux laptop. I have a Windows 8 laptop. How to root it with that?

Comment: I read about " how to root android manually" but it has a portion where it need Linux to root it ... is there any way to root it with windows?

Comment: While I cannot answer your question, I can give a quick hint: you might wish to check with our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) and [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) for available generic methods. Good luck!

Comment: I already used many applications to root my phone but it didn't work.

Comment: I want to root it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Before rooting your Galaxy Core GT-i8262, you need to know that CWM have bug to get caught in bootloop. But don't worry about that if your phone get caught in this situation. Here is [solution](https://vivekjib.wordpress.com/2015/03/30/troubleshot-for-all-problems-during-installing-custom-rom-in-samsung-galaxy-core-gt-i8262/)  for all problems during rooting of your phone. So, here I prefer TWRP (Team Win Recovery Project) over CWM , which has no such problems.

Here, you need to flash a custom recovery before because, after rooting if you you reboot then your root access vanishes. It happens as stock recovery sets them back. It was happening with me. Such a waste of time in rooting your phone again. Then, I got this process for permanent root access.

> Before you continue to the tutorial, you please prepare the following files:

1. Make sure your computer has installed [SAMSUNG USB Driver](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2l3fhgnqxl7hds/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.zip?dl=0) and [Odin307](https://www.dropbox.com/s/28vptbql6vujee7/Odin307.zip?dl=0). If not, please download.
2. Download file [TWRP Recovery](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r853hf0d3nocqzq/twrp2.7_arubaslim.ODIN.tar?dl=0), and save it on your computer.
3. Download flashable [SuperSu zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b55kznq64bx75d3/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.34.zip?dl=0) file.

**Steps to follow**:

**Step 1:** Download both the above files in a specific folder on your computer. The Odin that you’ve just downloaded is an essential tool & is must for installing TWRP recovery on any Android device. We remind our users that this tool is an illegal way & is not officially released by Samsung. Even though it will not cause any damage to your device unless you follow the instructions properly.

**Step 2:** Enable mode **USB Debugging** on your android by going to the settings, click on the phone, click on the version 7x formation, then you will receive Developer options.

**Step 3:** **Power off** your Galaxy core completely. You need to boot your mobile into downloading mode now.

**Step 4:** For Galaxy core, downloading mode can be entered by pressing & holding **Home button + Volume Down key + Power button** simultaneously until you see a warning message.

**Step 5:** Leave all the three buttons as soon as it appears. And just press the **Volume up** button to land into downloading mode.

**Step 6:** Now you need to **flash the TWRP recovery** on your device. For that keeping the device in download mode, connect it to computer using the USB cable.

**Step 7:** Launch the **Odin** Multi Downloader v3.07 that you’ve downloaded earlier. If your device is connected properly, then you’ll see that an *Added* message has been appeared on the Odin window. Along with that you’ll see the *ID:COM section has turned blue* with a random com port number below it. If this doesn’t happen, then ensure that proper device drivers are installed on your computer. You can install them from the link mentioned above.

[image: Working Odin Image]

**Step 8:** Make sure that the **Auto-Reboot and F.Reset Time** options present on the Odin window are checked. Do not tick or untick anything else.

[image: Regarding this step]

**Step 9:** On the Odin window, click on the **PDA** tab and browse to the **twrp2.7_arubaslim.ODIN.tar** recovery file which you have downloaded earlier & select it.

[image: related to step 9]

**Step 10:** After completing everything as mentioned above, simply press the **Start** button located on the Odin window to execute the TWRP flashing process. Your phone will automatically reboot itself while going through the process. It is *recommended not to touch or remove the USB cable* until the process completes.

[image: for step 10]

**Step 11:** Be patient until the TWRP flashing process completes. It will hardly take 2 minutes to complete. As soon as it completes, you’ll see the **ID:COM** section on the Odin window is turned **green** with the message **Pass** below it. Now you can safely remove the USB cable.

[image: step 11 image]

**Note:** Unfortunately due to some reason phone if the process fails or if Odin gets stuck or in case your device gets boot loops, then don’t panic. Just close the Odin window, remove and re-insert the battery from your device. Again go into downloading mode and repeat the whole procedure as given above.

**Step 12:** As all the flashing processes are completed now, let’s see whether the TWRP recovery is properly installed or not. For that, firstly **switch off** your Galaxy Core.

**Step 13:** Now boot into recovery mode. For Galaxy Core, recovery mode can be entered by pressing & holding **Volume Up key + Home button (Middle button) + Power button** simultaneously until you land into recovery mode. You’ll notice that TWRP Custom recovery is properly installed on your device.

**Step 13:** Now select ‘Wipe data/factory reset’ option followed by ‘Wipe Cache partition’ option for wiping out the data & caches present onto your phone memory. You can now reboot your phone by selecting ‘reboot system now’ option from the recovery mode itself.

**Step 14:** Now, copy SuperSu zip to your sdcard and put it in your phone.

**Step 15:** Open recovery mode again as stated above. Click Install, then choose your SuperSu zip file and flash it.

**Step 16:** Reboot to system and search for SuperSu app. If you have it, then you have full root access.

> > Don't forget to enjoy it by utilising ROOT access.

**Disclaimer:** To build this answer I used my experience ( Yup! I have same device ) and two main sources as follows: [first](http://www.droidthunder.com/root-install-cwm-recovery-samsung-galaxy-core-i8262/) and [second](http://www.dualandroid.com/2015/01/how-to-install-twrp-on-samsung-galaxy.html).